# Obfuscated Config Files: EHI Files for HTTP Injector

Tags: android, unpacking, java

So I have an ehi file, which is a configuration file for an Android App called [HTTP Injector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.injector&hl=pt_BR).
Of course when I try to see it as a simple text, I just get random characters.
What tool could I use to start trying to decrypt it?
I don't even know how to start and if someone could point time what type of encryption or obfuscation method was used I would be hugely grateful.

Here is a ehi file for demonstration: https://transfer.sh/91tbh/1_4999527475131187330.ehi

Thank you so much, and if my question is not accepted, please delete it.